# CSS properties of custom element not inherited to children

Tags: html, css, angular, custom-element

I'm working on an Angular 5 project and noticed some CSS properties are not inherited correctly from custom elements. For example, consider a custom component `foo`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  template: `
    <form>inside form</form>
    <div>inside form</div>
    outside
  `,
})
export class FooComponent { }
```

Now, I want to alter its `opacity` and `max-height`:

```
foo {
  opacity: 0.5;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, browsers seem to not inherit those properties correctly down to the `form` and `div` elements.

- Firefox (59) properly inherits `opacity`, but seems to ignore `max-height`.
- Chrome (64) doesn't inherit `opacity`, and also ignores `max-height` altogether.

I made a **[plunk demonstrating the issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/SSulJJ1GdPgV0zdBztJu?p=preview)**.

Is there some twist about how custom elements inherit CSS properties, or are those just browser bugs?

Comment: opacity and not inherited ! it's applied to the element AND to all its content ... same thing with max-height ... the issue with the cutom element, try `div` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `opacity` nor `max-height` are inherited properties to begin with. I think this is simply due to the fact that your custom foo component is inline by default, so a max-height for example isn’t even allowed to apply.

Add

```
foo { display: block; }
```

or

```
foo { display: inline-block; }
```

and check what result you get ...

Comment: i wiould also add a comment that there is no need to use custom element. Simply use div to avoid such issue and any bug

Comment: @TemaniAfif within a framework like Angular there might be a reason for a custom component, we don’t really know what the intended end result is here. I would just assume that it might be more complex than the simplified example.

Comment: Ah, yeah, the inline rendering is definitely a problem with max-height. However, this doesn't explain why opacity doesn't apply to children. I know, inherit is the wrong term, but even children of inline elements should *appear* with the parent's opacity, which is not the case here. But on the other hand, we're dealing with blocks inside an inline element, so it's invalid HTML and thus undefined behavior.

Comment: I am not too sure if this is actually invalid, I don’t know if the classical block/inline division applies to custom components, plus HTML5 isn’t so strict on block/inline any more, but rather specifies “content categories”, https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#kinds-of-content // You are right that it doesn’t explain the opacity behavior, that confused me with how your initial example displayed as well – but maybe that one is rather a browser bug then.

Answer (score 0):

try you add respectively tags to apply the css in the necessary tags. Ej:

```
    foo.opacity-test form {
       opacity: 0.5;
    }
```