# Apply background-color on custom tag with inside div

Tags: html, css, background

I Need to set background color for custom tag like page and then have div inside it
But I tried below cases and when I include div tag inside a cutom tag, surprisingly backgroundcolor is not getting applied.
This is tried in blank html page and hence no other css is added.

**This Works**

```
<page style="background:yellow">
    This is my entire web page
</page>

<div style="background:yellow">
    <div>
        This is my entire web page
    </div>
</div>
```

**This does not Work**

```
<page style="background:yellow">
    <div>
        This is my entire web page
    </div>
</page>

<anytag style="background:yellow">
    <div>
        This is my entire web page
    </div>
</anytag>
```

Comment: cutom tag are by default `inline` you need to make them block element because block element inside inline element isn't allowed

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/q/49322168/8620333

Comment: Custom element names [should be hyphenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545621/do-custom-elements-require-a-dash-in-their-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working, but we can't see because it is considering anytag or page as inline tag means if you add in **style="display: block"** or  **style="display: inline-block"** then you can find the difference

```
<anytag style="background:yellow;display:block">
    <div>
        This is my entire web page
    </div>
</anytag>
```

or using CSS

```
<page style="background:yellow">
    <div>
        This is my entire web page
    </div>
</page>
<style>
page{
  display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```

https://codepen.io/kaslab/pen/gqPpwp